# using set or List here in the code

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I  am newbie to java, I have a scenario, where i need to list the organisation types from the table:

Requirement : Just listing, no add or removing the elements,

As i understand the difference  between set and list:

**Set**:

Set is Unique collection of Objects.
Set is Un-ordered collection of Objects.

List:

List is non-unique collection of Objects.
List is ordered collection of Objects.

In my table i am having columns like:

```
id name      is_active
1  Lab        1
2  Pharmacy   2
3  Hospital   3
```

Maximum 10 rows

```
**Controller**:

List<OrgType> orgTypeList = organizationService.getAllOrgTypes(true);
OrgTypeResponse response = new OrgTypeResponse();
List<EntityDetail> orgTypeDetailList = new ArrayList<>();
EntityDetail orgTypeDetail;
for(OrgType orgType : orgTypeList) {
    orgTypeDetail = new EntityDetail();
    orgTypeDetail.setId(orgType.getId());
    orgTypeDetail.setName(orgType.getName());
    orgTypeDetailList.add(orgTypeDetail);
}
response.setStatus(ResponseStatusCode.SUCCESS);
response.setTotalOrgTypes((long)orgTypeDetailList.size());
response.setOrgTypes(orgTypeDetailList);
return response;


**Service** Implementaion:
List<OrgType> orgTypeList = orgTypeRepository.findByActive(active);
return orgTypeList;
```

This is  my EntityDetail class:

```
public class EntityDetail {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

My question here is, can i use the  Set instead of List

If Set is used, can i use TreeSet, because i need to show in the asc order of id

Or Leave the code, as it is

i just want the clarification,

Thanks

Comment: You can use set or list it depends on the requirement. Only difference list makes with set is duplicates are removed.HashSet consumes about 5.5 times more memory than ArrayList for the same number of elements (although they're both still linear).

If you don't care about uniqueness or the performance of contains, then use ArrayList

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of them but things to be kept in consideration:

> 1. Set although provides unique data, but that also has a cost.
> 2. In case, you are sure that table has unique names of organizations then you should opt for list.

It seems like you are using Spring with JPA, if that is the case, then you can use SORT interface(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort) to get sorted data.

Comment: yes default order is ascending but you can specify it to be desc also. You can pass SORT.DIRECTION as ASC or DESC Refer to the documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html   http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.Direction.html

Answer (score 2):

> My question here is, can i use the Set instead of List

Yes, without problem, just implement methods `equals` and `hashCode`.

> If Set is used, can i use TreeSet, because i need to show in the asc order of id

You can if class `EntityDetail` implements interface `Comparable<EntityDetail>`. This is necessary because `TreeSet` must know what is the natural order of the various `EntityDetail` objects.

For more details please see [Oracle docs on object ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) and [Javadoc for Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

Comment: "You can if class EntityDetail implements interface Comparable<EntityDetail>." Not necessarily since `TreeSet` has a overloaded constructor with a `Comparator` as argument.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks, nice catch! I usually prefer that class makes it explicit if it supports ordering of elements (by implementing ```Comparable```) so i forgot about that overloaded constructor.

Answer (score 0):

yes u can use SET instead of List in this scenario because SET will ensure that duplicate entries are eliminated. But making use of SET make sure that you have overridden "equals" and "hashcode" appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List` if you can make sure in your code that the details are added in it in the order that you want. If you are not sure of the order in which you add then you can use the `Collections.sort` method. For this you will also want to make your `OrgType` `implement`  the `Comparable` interface to provide a strategy to order the `OrgType` objects. In your case it is by id.

If you use `TreeSet`, the sorting is done automatically whenever you insert into the set thereby eliminating the use of `Collections.sort`but you will still have to provide an ordering strategy.

Have a look at [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

There are costs of using a Set because it maintains unique elements but because you have a maximum of 10 rows that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you need to override equals and hashcode methods and for sorting purpose you need to implement Comparable and implement compareTo method as follows:

```
class EntityDetail implements Comparable<EntityDetail>{
@Override
public int hashcode(){
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof EntityDetail)) {
        return false;
    }

    EntityDetail ed = (EntityDetail) o;

    return ed.name.equals(name) &&
            ed.id == id ;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(EntityDetail ed) {
    int compareId = ((EntityDetail) ed).getId();

    //ascending order
    return this.id - compareId;

    //descending order
    //return compareId - this.id;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i am searching for

Comment: @javalike In that case you should accept the answer.

Comment: But the above code makes me blink, for just listing the rows, am i need to use this much complex one

Comment: That is what you required. You need to do at least this. And this is not complex anymore.